# Inno setup script: How to control Languages section?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to control what languages are available for setup. I have defined myLanguage as:

```
; default is EN(glish) unless CMD parameter defined with /DmyLanguage="JA"
#ifndef myLanguage
  #define myLanguage "EN"
#endif
```

I have this in Languages sections:

```
[Languages]
Name: JA; MessagesFile: compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl; LicenseFile: {#MyFolder}\eulajp.txt; 
Name: EN; MessagesFile: compiler:Default.isl; LicenseFile: {#MyFolder}\eula.txt
```

Other sections I can control with: `Languages: JA` like this:

```
Source: {#MyFolder}\manual_jp.chm; DestDir: {app}; DestName: manual.chm; Languages: JA
```

but this option is not available in Languages section.

How can I offer JA language selection only when myLanguage="JA"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [#if](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_if.htm) in `[Languages]` section:

```
#if myLanguage == "JA" 
  Name: JA; MessagesFile: compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl; LicenseFile: {#MyFolder}\eulajp.txt; 
#endif
```

This also means you need to wrap all lines that will be run under selected language with same condition:

```
#if myLanguage == "JA" 
  Source: {#MyFolder}\manual_jp.chm; DestDir: {app}; DestName: manual.chm; Languages: JA
#endif
```

Otherwise we get compiler error:

> Directive or parameter "Languages" expression error: Parameter
> "Languages" includes an unknown language.